# Expect separator only if other two groups were satisfied

Tags: regex

I'm trying to make a regex that fits this need:

```
"a"   < Match group 1
"b"   < Match group 3
"a-b" < Match group 1, 2 and 3
"-"   < No match
"ab"  < No match
```

I was trying to make something like `(a?)(-b?)` but obviously this doesn't work like I want.

Edit:

Using a real example to explain better:

Regex I tried to use: `/remind (me|him)? about (this|that)?/gm`

```
 Text                   | Should match?
"remind me"             | Yes
"remind me about this"  | Yes
"remind me about that"  | Yes
"remind me about error" | No
"remind him about this" | Yes
"remind about"          | NO
"remind this"           | Yes
"remind error"          | No
"remind me"             | Yes
```

Edit explaining the reason:

I need this regex to split the data in fields, like "Who will be reminded?" "What is the reminder text?"

`remind me about this`
Person: me
Thing: this

`remind me`
Person: me
Thing: **missing**

`remind that`
Person: **missing**
Thing: that

`remind me this`
Error

`remind about this`
Error

Comment: Maybe `^(?!(?:ab|-)$)(a?)(-?)(b?)$`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Nice approach, but check edit

Comment: Yeah, my comment is also updated. Your question is unclear. You should explain what *real* problem you have. And state the regex flavor, too.

Comment: Just saw it, but that's very specific. I used `a` and `b` as examples, the real data is a long regex, I cant just repeat all the regex

Comment: It's not pretty and uses a positive lookbehind but this might also match `\b(?:(a(?=-b|$))|(?<=a)(-)(?=b)|(?:(?<=a-)|(?<=^))(b))\b`  https://regex101.com/r/3ZFeGZ/1

Comment: I used a simple example for brevity, I just edited so you understand it better

Comment: This could match the example data https://regex101.com/r/K1SSS9/1

Comment: You should want to get `remind me` in `remind me about error`. Why no match at all is expected?

Comment: @Thefourthbird The "this" should match the second group, not the first one.

Comment: @LuizLoyola What is the tool or language?

Comment: Have a look at the PHP solution [like this](https://3v4l.org/mBnTJ)

Answer (score 1):

Not totally sure, but maybe this helps. At least it satisfies your requirements: matches "a", "b", "a-b", and doesn't match ab and ba.

```
((a)-(b))|(?:\b(a)(?:[^b]|\b))|(?:(?:[^a]|\b))(b)\b
```

https://regex101.com/r/YOa83X/1/

Answer (score 1):

A systematic approach is to use branch reset for the sentence structures.
Each branch contains a different set of elements.

This uses a branch reset. The *Person* is in group 1, the *Thing* is in group 2.
If either is missing, it means it's not there.

`remind[ ](?|(him)[ ]about[ ](this)|(me)(?:[ ]about[ ](th(?:at|is)))?|()(th(?:at|is)))`

https://regex101.com/r/DPfvs0/1

---

If there is no branch reset available, the capture groups can be *paired* as
increments of 2, i.e. Person / Thing .
1 & 2
3 & 4
5 & 6

Just see which pair matched.

`remind[ ](?:(him)[ ]about[ ](this)|(me)(?:[ ]about[ ](th(?:at|is)))?|()(th(?:at|is)))`

https://regex101.com/r/xJUFbQ/1